# Bug when click on Confirm And Create This Account on Area 51

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

I want to join Area 51, but in the joining steps, when I use the `Confirm And Create This Account` button in the page with this link, [Confirm Your New Account](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/join?ssrc=votedialog&returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdiscuss.area51.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F20983%2Fwhat-is-the-definition-of-deep-web-in-the-context-of-the-deep-web-proposal), I receive:

> Page not found. We couldn't find the page you requested. However, we were able to snap this picture.

Message in page with this link, [Page Not Found](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm).

Comment: Also a note to reproduce - this link is given when someone tries to vote on an answer - a dialog pops up with a link to join. Following through from area51 'Login' (to post an answer, for example) leads to a separate login page - which appears to work.

Comment: This really belongs on the Area 51 meta, or on Meta Stack Exchange.